# Limit Points Explanation required

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In my lecture notes for my course it gives a brief description of limit points that I'm finding hard to grasp.

> A real number a is called a limit point of a sequence $s_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$, if there exists a subsequence $s_{n_k}$ such that $a=\lim_{k\to\infty}s_{n_k}$

This makes sense to me for convergent sequences, as all subsequences converge to the same limit as their respective sequence. However for a divergent sequence for example $s_n=(-1)^n$, my notes say that the limit points are both -1 and 1. However if I take the subsequence $n_k=2k$ then the subsequence become $s_{n_k}=(-1)^{2k}=1^k=1$

Taking the $\lim_{k\to\infty}{1^k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}{1}=1$ the sequence seems to have only 1 as its limit point. I've stumbled upon other definitions for limit points, describing neighbourhoods, but don't quite understand them. I'm only a puny first year, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

George

Comment: Limit points just mean a point that is really "close" to the sequence. $x$ is a limit point of $s_n$ if any open interval around $x$ contains infinitely many points from $s_n$

Comment: I'm not sure the first sentence of your definition is useful, @mtiano. I would never consider $-1$ "very close" to the sequence $(-1)^k$. The definition is correct, however.

Comment: The definition should be $a=\lim_{k\to\infty} s_{n_k}$, not $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was just trying to give some intuition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right. Corrected.

Comment: @George Another term for this is "accumulation point," which gives another intuition. $a_n=(-1)^n$ "accumulates" around both $-1$ and $+1$.

Comment: If you want to understand this better, look up the limit superior and limit inferior

Answer (score 4):

$s_{2n}$ is a subsequence of $s_n$, whose limit is $1$, hence $1$ is a limit point of $s_n$. Similarly, $s_{2n+1}$ is a subsequence of $s_n$, whose limit is $-1$, hence $-1$ is also a limit point of $s_n$.

Comment: Thanks so the set of all subsequences will produce the limit points rather than one example.

Comment: An alternative view is that the existence of a limit is also equivalent to a "neighborhood condition". In other words, if every nbd of a point contains an element of the sequence, then that point is a limit point of the sequence. So in your case, if you consider the point x=-1, is there a neighborhood of -1 that contains an element from the sequence? Sure. Any nbd of -1 contains an element from the sequence since -1 itself is an element of the sequence. This point of view is nice in that it extends not just to sequences, but to sets too.

Comment: Surely from that reasoning any point in the sequence is a limit point?

Comment: Yes, he should have said that every *deleted* neighborhood of the point contains an element of the sequence. (A deleted neighborhood of a point is a neighborhood of that point with the point itself removed.)

Comment: @MPW That still doesn't work for $a_n=(-1)^n$. This neighborhood definition works for limit points of sets, but needs clarification for sequences which can have repeated elements. It should be: For any open interval $I$ around $a$ and any natural $N$, there is an $n>N$ such that $a_n\in I$.

Comment: @MattBrenneman: You are using the wrong terminology. The elements of the sequence are in the *closure* of the set of points in the sequence, but none need be *limit point* of that set. Distinguish between isolated and adherent points.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, you are right, of course. I was thinking of the underlying set (as in my last comment), and had in mind something like $\{1/n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where elements aren't repeated. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MPW I think defns do vary, and you just have to be very clear about what defns you are using. There are standard texts (such as Goldberg's "Methods of Real Analysis") where any point in a set is taken to be a limit point of the set. The condition for a deleted nbd is then used to define "cluster point". But, I'm sure there are other texts that define things differently.

Comment: @MattBrenneman No, your definition is for elements in the closure of the set, whereas the limit point of a sequence is a different thing than a limit point of a set.

Comment: So for the sequence $(-1)^n$ if I take a nbd of radius 1/2 around the point 1, it will give all the repeated iterations of 1 and therefore have another point other than itself in the nbd (even though it is the same value) and so is a limit point. This would mean any repeated value in a sequence is always a limit point?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Agreed: limit point of a set and sequence are not the same thing. Thanks

Comment: @George1811   Yes it does, because you can construct a subsequence of those values which repeat, which will be a constant sequence, and therefore converge.

Comment: @George1811  Although you probably already know this, I'll just re-iterate the nbd condition for a point x to be a limit point of a sequence. "x is a limit point of the sequence (x_n) iff for every epsilon > 0 and for every natural number N, there exists a natural number n > N such that x_n is in the epsilon nbd of x."  If you think about this, you'll realize that this is equivalent to the condition that a subsequence of (x_n) converges to x (good exercise).

Comment: @MattBrenneman Thanks makes sense now. My lecture notes seem to skim over certain topics and bring them back up at exam time.

Comment: @George1811  You're welcome. It's tricky (as you can see), but it points out the importance of defns in math. It is probably fair to say that not all textbooks are equally good at clearly explaining key defns/concepts. Looking around for one that suits you and that you understand might help  a bit.  Anyhow, it was a good question; just keep asking and working away at it!